# непонятная кодировка при ассинхронном парсинге данных

Tags: python, web-scraping

Есть код

```
semaph=asyncio.Semaphore(15)
async def get_site_content(url):
    async with semaph:
        headers={'User-Agent':useragent.random}
        async with aiohttp.ClientSession() as session:
            async with session.get(url) as resp:
                text = await resp.content.read()
                print(str(text))
                with open(f"tryAsync/{time.time()}.html","w") as file :
                    file.write(str(text))
                    print(file.encoding)
                await asyncio.sleep(random.randint(4,10))
    return
```

при выполенинии даного кода html файл получается с непонятной кодировкой.
Пример:

\xe2\x89\xa1 \xd0\x9d\xd0\xb8\xd0\xb6\xd0\xbd\xd1\x8f \xd0\xb1\xd1\x96\xd0\xbb\xd0\xb8\xd0\xb7\xd0\xbd\xd0\xb0 - \xd0\xb2 \xd1\x96\xd0\xbd\xd1\x82\xd0\xb5\xd1\x80\xd0\xbd\xd0\xb5\xd1\x82 \xd0\xbc\xd0\xb0\xd0\xb3\xd0\xb0\xd0\xb7\xd0\xb8\xd0\xbd\xd1\x96 069.net.ua - 3-\xd0\xb0 \xd1\x81\xd1\x82\xd0\xbe\xd1\x80\xd1\x96\xd0\xbd\xd0\xba\xd0\xb0

Думаю, проблема из-за асинхронных функций,поскольку раньше с ними не работал,надеюсь на совет,любую дополнительную информацию кину,пишите в комменты

```
semaph=asyncio.Semaphore(15)
async def get_site_content(url):
    async with semaph:
        headers={'User-Agent':useragent.random}
        async with aiohttp.ClientSession() as session:
            async with session.request(method="GET",url=url) as resp:
                text = await resp.text(encoding="utf-8",errors="replace")
                print(text)
                with open(f"tryAsync/{time.time()}.html","w") as file :
                    file.write(str(text))
                await asyncio.sleep(random.randint(4,10))
    return
```

Comment: Вполне понятная, это экранированное представление UTF-8 текста. Зачем вы пытаетесь записать **байтовую** строку `text` в файл `file`, открытый в **текстовом** режиме? Выберите что-то одно — или  преобразуйте строку в юникодную, или откройте файл в бинарном режиме. Асинхронные функции здесь вообще ни при чём

Comment: изменил код на 
 file.write(text.decode('utf-8')) - не помогло
выдает данную ошибку:
UnicodeDecodeError: 'utf-8' codec can't decode byte 0xcf in position 22723: invalid continuation byte

Comment: Теперь это означает, что сайт вам присылает повреждённый UTF-8 текст. Так как правильно раскодировать его невозможно, то остаётся только единственный вариант — использовать байтовую строку и открывать файл в бинарном режиме (и выкинуть `str(...)` нафиг, конечно же)

Comment: Самое интересное что метод print() нормально выводит текст (читаемо).Также,почему я грешил на асинхрон,в синронном коде все нормально работает

Comment: Может, print срабатывает на каком-то другом url, в котором нет повреждённых данных и поэтому работает?

Comment: Вряд-ли в таком случае файлы бы нормально сохраняли,чего не происходит(сохраняет пустые). Да и синхронный код обрабатывает все страницы без проблем

Comment: Ваши комментарии не очень соответствуют действительности. Я подготовил битый UTF-8 файл, запустил показанный вами код — и print отпечатал нечитаемое месиво, как и ожидалось https://i.stack.imgur.com/hf2CO.png

Comment: да,извините,это старый код нормально выводился,щас в текст добавляю

Comment: Ну вот, вы ещё и новые изменения от меня скрывали, оказывается

Comment: Ну если вы уж декодировали с `errors="replace"`, то теперь все файлы записываются нормально и непустые https://i.stack.imgur.com/zp4F1.png

Comment: При том что принт нормально вывод,даже кирилицу. Пример:
     <br><br>
        <div style="margin: 10px;">
            Ми раді вітати Вас на нашій новій сторінці!<br><br>
    Ваші знижки та бонуси від замовлень, зроблених раніше, збережено.<br>
    Ми відправили Вам лист з посиланням, для реєстрації на цій сторінці.<br>
    Перевірте, будь ласка, вашу пошту і, можливо, спам.<br>
    Вибачте за незручності.

Кстати файлы пустые при записи и выдае и выдает ошибку:  UnicodeEncodeError: 'charmap' codec can't encode character '\u2261' in position 1212: character maps to <undefined>

Comment: Если у вас Windows, то это, возможно, из-за того, что кодировкой по умолчанию является не utf-8, попробуйте указать её явно: `open(f"tryAsync/{time.time()}.html","w", encoding="utf-8")`

Comment: Сработало,спасибо большое

Comment: (но если вдруг окажется, что какой-то из сайтов использует кодировку не utf-8, то всё это опять вылезет боком, и возможно использование байтовой строки с бинарным файлом может оказаться всё-таки более универсальным решением)

Comment: Это конешно не мое собачее дело, а зачем записывать на диск парсили бы сразу?

Comment: это на время разваботки,потом удалю